# A question about kernels and linear operators

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am reading a lecture note of functional analysis.
In the highlighted line, the inclusion of one kernel by the other kernel implies the existence of a linear operator. I found a proof for a simpler case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109364/ker-s-subset-ker-t-leftrightarrow-exists-r-t-rs?rq=1). But, is there any proof or reference about the general case including this case below (i.e. two linear operators with the same domain yet different codomains). Also, I wonder how the functional $\psi_0$ can be extended to the entire space $\mathbb{C}^n$ as mentioned. Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very generally (even for sets or other algebraic structures), if $f:A\to B$ is surjective, $g:A\to C$ is such that its kernel contains the kernel of $f$, in the sense that $f(x)=f(y)\implies g(x)=g(y)$, then $g$ leads through $B$:
Simply assign $f(x)\mapsto g(x)$, which is well defined by the hypothesis and covers all elements of $B$ by surjectivity.

For the other question, consider a basis of the subspace $T(\mathcal X)$,  extend it to a basis of $\Bbb C^n$, and define the map arbitrarily on the new basis vectors.

Comment: Thank you. After drawing a diagram for this, I thought that 1) ker(f) contains ker(g), instead of ker(g) containing ker(f). 2) To g(x) there corresponds f(x), instead of f(x) being mapped to g(x). Right?

Comment: Well, you can exchange the roles of the letters $f,g$, but then $g$ should be the one assumed surjective. So, briefly: no. I think I wrote it correctly.